# View closing when a presented sheet has been dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I use sheets for various different reasons, all inside of navigation views within my app.

I'm currently having a problem where when someone dismisses the sheet, the entire view closes and exits the navigation view back to the home screen, a similar result to if it the presentationmode.wrappedvalue was being dismissed.

I would love to solve this, my necessary code is below

**FEEDVIEW.SWIFT SHORTENED**

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @State var navigateTo: AnyView?
    @State var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
     NavigationView {
        Menu {
         Button {
             self.navigateTo = AnyView(FeedbackView())
             self.isActive = true
         } label: {
          Label("Give us feedback", systemImage: "arrowshape.zigzag.right")
         }
      } label: {
       Text("example for stack overflow")
      }
    }
    .background(NavigationLink(destination: AnyView(self.navigateTo), isActive: $isActive) { EmptyView() })
    }
}
```

**FEEDBACKVIEW.SWIFT SHORTENED**

```
struct FeedbackView: View {
  @State private var showingSheet = false
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      showingSheet.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("click here")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
       Text("sheet")
           .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
    }
  }
}
```

When this sheet is swiped away the entire view goes back to the feedview.swift view.

I hope this shortened code works to replicate my issues, if anything additional is needed I'm more than happy to provide it.

Comment: `AnyView` is highly discouraged, You can watch Demystify SwiftUI for more. You should also never hold views in State variables they become outdated and cause many issues. Try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials it seems like you come from some programming background but SwiftUI is not like other frameworks

Comment: Please see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dismissaction

Comment: there is an issue with that code sample i guess u miss placed it add the background modifier to the menu not the NavigationView. I tested your code it works fine with me when dismissing the sheet it keeps me on the FeedBackView try running the code on different iOS versions and i recommend  you using NavigationStack instead of NavigationView because it's deprecated started from iOS 16 and since you are using presentationDetents which is supported starting from iOS 16 so you better use NavigationStack